# SVG to DXF with Inkscape via Windows CMD batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, terminal, inkscape

I have a folder with multiple SVG's, and want them to be converted to DXF on a Windows.
I have installed Inkscape, and added the bin directory to my path.

With the following batch-file I'm trying to do the conversion, but CMD gives a message with '%myfile was unexpected at this time.'

```
for %myfile in (*.svg) do $(inkscape --export-type="dxf" %myfile.svg --export-filename=%myfile.dxf); done
```

Not sure what the correct syntax should be, to do this correctly or I'm missing something.

Edit:

I understand now that it's also important to use %% in a batch file. The $() wasn't working aswell. So my batch file is now like the following:

```
for %%s in (*.svg) do inkscape --export-type="dxf" %%s --export-filename=%%s.dxf
```

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key to find out how the command works.

Comment: I have no idea from your latest edit, if you've now solved your issue, because you've not said so. However, based upon the output I've already told you to produce, I'll assume that ```%%s.dxf``` should be ```%%~ns.dxf```. I'd also advise that ```%%s```, should be ```"%%~s"``` and ```%%~ns.dxf``` should be ```"%%~ns.dxf"``` too.

Comment: Almost @Compo, I see now output like filnames with 'filename.svg.dxf' that's incorrect of course. That's why I need the modifier that you're suggesting, to get the file names only, so not with the extension.

Comment: I've edited out the solution from your question. If you want to post it, please do that as an answer…

Answer (score 0):

We use a CMD-batch file, so variables need to have double %. We can loop over the SVG files in the folder with `(*.svg)`, and use them each in a variable called %s. For each file we can use inkscape (bin directory needs to be added to PATH) to convert to DXG file format, with `--export-type="dxg"` and the name with `export-filename=%%~ns.dxg`. We need to use ~n because we don't want to use the file extension .svg and add that to .dxg. With that modifier we skip the extension. So the full correct line/syntax should be:

```
for %%s in (*.svg) do inkscape --export-type="dxg" %%s --export-filename=%%~ns.dxg
```